# Colour cannot be applied in material mode

Tags: texturing, materials, color, color-management, object-mode

Whenever I change the object from solid mode to material mode to apply colour I am facing issues:

1. The outline of the object I created vanishes completely. It shows an orange outline only.
   [[image: object in solid mode][1]]
   [image]
2. When I go to apply colour, it does not respond to the command.
   [image: colour does not come]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and is [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos candidate for  canned comments meta?

Comment: @batFINGER I've been renovating my canned comments, I could add it there as well ;)